# Mold remediators removed portion of house frame - how to repair?

Tags: framing, windows, leak, structural, mold

We are currently having all of the windows in our house replaced with new construction windows. We knew the old ones leaked, and we knew we had moisture and probably mold in the walls. We have mold remediators working in parallel with the window contractors, though these mold remediators seem to not generally repair anything they destroy as part of the remediation process. I wasn't too worried about that with respect to things like drywall and baseboards and cabinetry, but they removed some pretty significant portions of the frame in one room.

Fortunately this is the top floor of the house, so the affected frame is only holding up one level above it. See the first image for a wide view of the entire affected area. The second image shows a closeup of the right side, where the damage was worse (the sill plate was mostly dry-rotted away anyway, so was probably already ineffective structurally) and where they were more aggressive in their removal. The third image shows the left side.

I'd like to know what people think is the best way to repair this. No, I'm not suggesting DIY. Just trying to inform myself. The guy who heads the window contracting crew also builds houses and understand framing very well, at least so he claims. But sometimes he's hard to communicate with, e.g. he was actually the first to notice this framing demo and said he didn't even want to install the new window (i.e. add more weight) until he repaired the frame, which it sounded like he was offering to do. But then the next day when I was not home he installed the window anyway. I will talk to him tomorrow and see if he still wants to repair the frame. But I'm wondering in a very general sense how it would be done, and also if I should be consulting some other expert, or be more worried than I already am (the removal of the triple stud (I don't know the real term) on the right particularly concerns me right now. FWIW I was a structural engineer for a decade in an earlier career, but for metal airframes, not wooden house frames.

To make matters worse, in this one area we still are not 100% sure what the source of water intrusion was. All other leaks in the house were clearly faulty windows. This one it does not appear so. The mold guys think it was the stucco, and think we should leave the drywall open for now, and after 100% completion of the window job and stucco repair/paint, we should blast the side of the house with water and see if anything shows up inside the wall. The window guy thinks the spacer joint between the first and second floors of the house was leaking through a nail hole, and offered to break all the stucco around that area and inspect further. I like that idea, especially since I'm guessing that repairing the frame would be easier from that angle as well. But I'm curious to hear thoughts from others. Thanks if you've read this far!

[image: wide view]

[image: right side]

[image: left side]

Comment: Can you take an outside photo with the roof profile on this wall.

Comment: Is your stucco built on a rainscreen?  or just tar paper and then chicken wire?  You should have an air gap between the stucco and the sheathing or an airgap stucco backer fabric.  What year is the house?  do you have header flashings with back dams for the new windows?